# FFMPEG - convert into variable framerate by removing duplicate frames

Tags: ffmpeg

I have slideshow video (i.e. 10GB)   1080p quality (30 FPS), and each image lasts about 15 seconds ...

Is there any option with FFMPEG, to convert those 15 seconds periods from 30 FPS(because they are just duplicate frames)  into i.e. 1 fps, thus, making the video small size...

the only periods that should keep original FPS is the fadeout period  from image to image (that lasts 3 seconds... they are not duplicate frames, each frame is different because of fade-out effect).

Comment: What's the total duration?

Comment: @Mulvya please, dont mind that , I am just illustrating the case, actually i have many slideshow video files... just want to get a solution exactly what question i had.

Comment: I will, once you report the total duration for the 10GB _or_ bitrate for a typical file.

Comment: @Mulvya As i have said, i have not 10GB file actually, I just articulated that to express easily what i  wanted. I have many slideshow videos (some of them is 1 gb, some of them is 2 gb) that are slideshows created from different images.  bitrate is variable ( 4000-8000 kbps)

Comment: Then you just need to re-encode with ffmpeg using a mid CRF value, like between 24-27. I-frames will be smaller but mainly P-frames which are static will only take few dozen bytes to store. Actually decimating the static frames **and** keeping the fade sequences at full FPS can be done but will be cumbersome and subject to trial and error. Just doing a simple re-encode will get you most of the size savings you would have gotten.

Comment: @Mulvya thanks for help. post it s answer, i will choose.   p.s.  example commands will be good, i dont fully know how to do what you say....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to re-encode with ffmpeg using a mid CRF value, like between 24-27. I-frames will be smaller but mainly P-frames which are static will only take few dozen bytes to store. Actually decimating the static frames and keeping the fade sequences at full FPS can be done but will be cumbersome and subject to trial and error. Just doing a simple re-encode will get you most of the size savings you would have gotten

Basic command is

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -crf 25 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

Comment: and how is that possible, to drop framerate to i.e.  1 (when there are duplicate frames sequence)? It will be much saving for me (have slideshows at 4K, with 30 FTPS in vain, where most of the time,the FTPS is needed only at fadeout sequences..